# Expression Builder: Timestamp to date

Tags: type-conversion, azure-data-factory

I have a Look up activity to retrieve an employee ID. For this purpose I compare a date with a timestamp which of course does not work.
How can I convert the timestamp to a date in the  Data Flow expression builder?

The Timestamp format is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss','Z'
The date formate is yyyy-MM-dd

Can someone help?

THanks in advance!

Grtz D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this expression:

```
toDate(toString(name of your column))
```

Default format of `toDate` function is yyyy-[M]M-[d]d. If you need other format, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#todate).